# Can you use adjectives right before a verb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

[image: Doujima kun chapter 25 page 5]

I came across a character saying '完全逃した' which I found as odd as it is a na adjective(完全) + a verb(逃した). Is it allowed use an adjective directly before a verb)?

Comment: Some nouns and na-/no-adjectives including 一生, 突然 and 絶対 work also as an adverb on its own, but 完全 is not one of those at least in standard Japanese. I feel 完全 is infrequently used like an adverb in slangy conversations, but this is a non-standard usage.

Answer (score 5):

完全 is a noun, and it acts as an adjective when suffixed with な; it can also act as adverb when suffixed with に, which I think it's the case in that balloon: they just left out the に, but 完全 is acting adverbially, so the sentence means something like "I completely missed my chance to say it".